# Java version upgrade

Tags: java, security

I've upgrade my Java JDK installation to a later minor release version (e.g. 1.8.131 to 1.8.144).

Should I recompile project source code to get any security benefits from bytecode generation or should I just run the old bytecode on the updated JRE?

Any real world examples welcome as I will need to justify this to the project team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken.

The java compiler doesn't do much, besides turning Java source into bytecode. There are few special optimisations. And no "security" related things at all.

And keep in mind: all invokations of **system** methods that your code is doing - will be going to Java8 classes on a Java8 VM.

Thus there is no pressing reason to update "everything".